# unable to add key value pairs to complex object in php

Tags: php, object, key

I'm trying to create the follwing object in PHP:

```
$obj= {abc@gmail.com:[usr:130,fname:'Bob',lname:'thekid',news:0,wres:1,SWAGLeaders:0]}
```

ultimately $obj will have a number of email addresses each with its own array.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->{$user[0]['email']}=[];
```

where `$user[0]['email]` contains the email address.

my problem is I don't know how to add the elements to the array

Comment: can anybody explain why someone would vote down this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path if you really need an object.

```
$user[0]['email'] = 'test';
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->{$user[0]['email']} = ['usr' => 130, 'fname' => 'Bob', 'lname' => 'thekid', 'news' => 0, 'wres' => 1, 'SWAGLeaders' => 0];
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Here's the output.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/035266a29425193251b74f0757bdd0a3580a31bf

But, I personally don't see a need for an object, I'd go with an array with a bit simpler syntax.

```
$user[0]['email'] = 'test';
$obj[$user[0]['email']] = ['usr' => 130, 'fname' => 'Bob', 'lname' => 'thekid', 'news' => 0, 'wres' => 1, 'SWAGLeaders' => 0];
echo json_encode($obj);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13c1b5308907588afc8721c1354f113c641f8788

Answer (score 1):

The same way you assigned the array to the object in the first place.

```
$user[0]['email'] = "abc@gmail.com";
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{$user[0]['email']} = [];

$obj->{$user[0]['email']}[] = "Element 1";
$obj->{$user[0]['email']}[] = "Element 2";
$obj->{$user[0]['email']}[] = "Element 3";

var_dump($obj);
```

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["abc@gmail.com"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Element 1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Element 2"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "Element 3"
  }
}
```